# Using Xcode 8 install Cocoapods and AFNetworking

Tags: cocoapods, afnetworking, xcode8

```
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git /var/folders/vm/2w09wypj79931z2gbs0zvcv80000gn/T/d20161018-7424-1oqafh4 --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 3.1.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/vm/2w09wypj79931z2gbs0zvcv80000gn/T/d20161018-7424-1oqafh4'...
fatal: unable to access  Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out:
```

[image: image description here]

Comment: Could you try to reformat your question to make it more readable?

Comment: Do you actually have access to https://www.github.com ?

Comment: Yes ,I can normally access the browser in the browser github.com